# How to checksum files from filename on Linux

Tags: linux, checksum, linux-terminal, data-integrity, verification

I have many files tagged with a CRC checksum on their filename on a Windows machine. Example:

```
filename_[000000].extension
```

I know there are a lot of options for Linux based systems to check/calculate CRC checksums, but I'm not aware of any that can calculate a file's checksum and then "stamp" that checksum by renaming the file or verify the checksum by comparing a calculation result with the checksum on the filename.

Is there some kind of terminal command that can replicate this kind of checksum verification?

Comment: not a terminal application but this might be useful to many people https://github.com/tristanheaven/gtkhash

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can combine good 'single-purpose' Linux tools to do this. By "CRC", I am assuming you mean CRC32.

**To add the checksum to each file**:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f |while read -r FILE; do
    mv -i "$FILE" "${FILE%.*}"_[$(crc32 "$FILE")]."${FILE##*.}"
done
```

**To verify the correct checksum**:

```
crc32 *
```

For each file that is already tagged, `crc32` will display either `OK` or (for example) `BAD 93ed200a != 299f65cb` after the filename.

**If you don't have the crc32 binary**:

```
sudo apt install libarchive-zip-perl
```

Comment: If this works it is a much nicer solution then the one I came up with.  I could not find crc32 on my (standard Ubuntu 20.04) install - what version of crc32 did you use and where did you get it?

Comment: @davidgo - Thanks for the information. I'm also using Ubuntu 20.04. The binary seems to be from the the package `libarchive-zip-perl`, which is a dependency of `libopenoffice-oodoc-perl` which I installed for some scripts I use. I added this information to my answer.

Comment: Thank you very much @bitinerant ! This replicates perfectly my workflow in Windows. Would it be possible to only print BAD results?

Comment: @iz_been - You're welcome. "*Would it be possible to only print BAD results?*" Sure: `crc32 * |grep -v 'OK$'`

Answer (score 1):

The linux command line is very modular and I can think of many ways of doing this.  its likely not something you can elegantly do as a single command solution unless you run a script, but the logic is simple - Do a checksum, then rename the file, appending the checksum.  I note I've useed sha512 sums, but you can do most other types of checksums, including md5 which might be shorter.

I came up with an only sligthly 1-liner as follows:

```
mv test.file test-\[`sha512sum test.file| cut -f1 -d" "`\].file
```

To make this more generic would be messy at the command line, but fairly easy with a script - you would use the script to split the file into the part before and after the extension.

Verifying the output would depend on the exact format of the renamed file and this would likely want a script to do this because of the formatting of the filename.

Programatically Checking the result is possible but quite a bit more complex as it would be a horribly complex 1-liner.

Here is a script which would verify the file created with the above 1 liner

```
#! /bin/bash

if [ $1. == '.' ]
then
    echo Usage: $0 filename
fi

FILENAMECHECKSUM=`echo $1 | cut -f2 -d'[' | cut -f1 -d']'`
FILECONTENTCHECKSUM=`sha512sum $1 | cut -f1 -d" "`

if [ $FILENAMECHECKSUM == $FILECONTENTCHECKSUM ]
then
    echo "Checksum OK"
else
    echo "Checksum mismatch"
fi
```